# ¿Como evito que mysql update elimine los 0 a la izquierda?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, update

Estoy haciendo un `UPDATE` en mysql y al ejecutarlo ingresa el dato nuevo pero si tiene un 0 a la izquierda lo elimina. Como puedo evitar esto?
Ya verifique en el código de php anterior a ejecutar la consulta y la variable todavía tiene el cero a la izquierda, es en el `UPDATE` que se elimina.

```
die(var_dump($pwdNueva));// 0123

$sql="UPDATE `socios` SET `password`= $pwdNueva WHERE socios.ci = $ci";

$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

Luego de este código el dato insertado en la base es 123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente el problema estaba en que faltaban comillas `''` en la sentencia sql.

Con esta sentencia el update sql eliminaba los 0 a la izquida. :

```
$sql="UPDATE `socios` SET `password`= $pwdNueva WHERE socios.ci = $ci";
```

Encerre en comillas simples la variable $pwdNueva y funciono.

```
$sql="UPDATE `socios` SET `password`= '$pwdNueva' WHERE socios.ci = '$ci'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Ese error lo ocaciona PHP porque entiende que es un numero lo ideal es usar comillas simples:

```
$pwdNueva = '0123';
```

Pero lo más probable es que lo quieras recibir desde un formulario por lo cual no tendria que haber problema ya que lo tomaria por un string... Aunque si lo usas en en la vida real tendrias que verificar que fuera una contraseña segura (que fuera un minimo de 8 carcteres una mayusculas....) y ponerle un hash a la contraseña para mayor seguridad:

```
$pwdNueva = hash('sha512', $pwdNueva);
```

Y lo guardas BD en un CHAR(128) tambien podrias usar otras medidas de seguridad pero eso lo aprendes con el tiempo. Espero haberte ayudado y mucho exito en tu proyecto.

Comment: Toda la razón, guardar contraseñas sin encriptar es una mala practica.

Comment: Hamlet como tu dices los datos los recibo desde un form (voy a editar el post con el codigo previo), y cuando recibo los datos del form todavía no se han eliminado los 0 a la izq. En la base de datos el tipo de dato es VARCHAR de 160 caracteres pensando en como tu dices encriptar la clave pero eso ya lo hare mas adelante.

Comment: Pues es muy raro que pase esto, hace años tuve el mismo problema y lo  resolví pero no recuerdo como exactamente... Pero una solución al problema es encriptando la contraseña con el sha512 o si necesitas la contraseña ocupa una encriptación de 2 sentidos. Si de todos modos vas hacer la encriptación hazlo de una vez.

Answer (score 0):

pienso que debes de verificar el tipo de dato en tu BD, si dices que tu campo password a modificar es un entero, no te guardará el cero a la izquierda, puedes modificar el tipo de dato o también te recomiendo que cheques la propiedad de ZEROFILL

Aquí un ejemplo de como usarlo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256469/what-is-the-benefit-of-zerofill-in-mysql

Pero yo lo pondría como varchar y si quiero solo permitir que sean números lo puedo restringir usando javascript por ejemplo

Comment: En la base de datos el tipo de dato que utilizo como tu dices es varchar. por lo que entendi del ZEROFILL completa siempre la cantidad de digitos con un cero  pero en mi caso no siempre voy a tener 0 a la izquierda